# Create a custom commandButton and Input components

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, custom-component

I'm trying to implement a custom JS2 command button using UICommand with the latest HTML5 attributes. But, how  i can handles the action and actionListener attribues? The UICommand will save thier values, this done by the JSF2 runtime, but how i can know exactly which methode of which bean that i should excute after the button activation by the user in the renderer class at the 'encodeBegin methode'. The source code for the [PrimeFaces commandButon](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandButton.xhtml) renderer class, available [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces/3.1/org/primefaces/component/commandbutton/CommandButtonRenderer.java?av=f) is complicated.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for the help, "how i can hanlde CommandButton  actions using Jquery, Ajax and JSF2", this 's really what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you need extend that class (CommandButton or CommandButtonRendered) and override exactly the methods that does not work as you want. Like this for CommandButtonRenderer:

```
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer;

/**
 *
 * @author nuno_marinho
 */
public class MyCommandButtonRenderer extends CommandButtonRenderer {

    @Override
    ...

}
```

or like this for CommandButton:

```
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer;
import org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton;

/**
 *
 * @author nuno_marinho
 */
public class MyCommandButton extends CommandButton {

    @Override
    ...

}
```

And finally you need define the changes for component in faces-config.xml like this:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.CommandButton</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.yourpackage.commandButton.MyCommandButton</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

I hope that explaination can help you!

Comment: Thanks Nuno for ur help. I looking for a way to get the value of the action & actionListener attributes from the associated EL specified by the web developers, Does the UICommand JSF2 commponents handle the task?

Comment: Then, how ican invoke the value in the EL to get the methode invoked during the invoke application phase? Is the JSF runtime responsible for excuting the methods specified in action & actionListener attributes?

Comment: I can implement a HTML5 button in the JSF specification; using UIcommand, but my problem is, how i can handle the button 's actions during the render phase.
      For PrimeFaces, it uses 'PF.ab(source,event,update);return false;'  how does this solution passe the bean and the methode IDs to the jsf runtime ?